# Validation for chechboxes

Tags: javascript, html

So, there are checkboxes:

```
<repeat group="{{ @directions }}" value="{{ @direction }}" counter="{{ @key }}">
    <label class="option block option-primary m10">                                 
        <input type="hidden" name="directions_{{@key}}" id="{{@direction->id}}" value="{{@direction->id}}">                                 
        <span class=""></span>{{ @direction->name }}
    </label>
</repeat>
```

and i need to do validation for them (at least 1 must be checked). In validation script, which i must use (yes, must) you have to give every input the same name. Meanwhile, every input must have unique name, because i need to take them out of POST after. And this is my problem: how to do this? I think, it is smth with several inputs and *hidden*.

And sample of validation script:

```
rules: {
  par1: {
    required: true
  },
messages: {
  par1: {
    required: 'Enter your name'
  },
```

Par1 is input/inputs name.

Comment: This doesn't look like pure javascript/html...

Comment: Yeah, this is framework (Fat3).